# odbc_iter error: the trait `serde::ser::Serialize` is not implemented for `odbc_iter::value::Value`

Tags: rust, serde

Please help, I got this serde not implemented for trait error when i am trying out odbc_iter example

```
    let row = db.query::<ValueRow>("SELECT 'hello world', CAST(42 AS INTEGER), CAST(10000000 AS BIGINT)")
    .expect("failed to run query").single().expect("failed to fetch row");  

    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&row).expect("failed to serialize"));
```

error[E0277]: the trait bound `odbc_iter::value::Value: serde::ser::Serialize` is not satisfied
    --> src\main.rs:94:42

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the same Serde version in both libraries?

Comment: Hello Kotauskas, my toml file:  [dependencies]
odbc-iter="0.2.5"
serde="1.0.114"
serde_json="1.0.55"

Comment: `serde_json` seems to have `default-features = false` for Serde. Try replacing `serde = "1.0.114"` with `serde = {version = "1.0.110", default-features = false}`, that's the exact line from `serde_json`'s manifest.